# access local server from another device

Tags: networking, server

I have apache on ubuntu 19.04. I can access my local host using 127.0.0.1 or my local ip like 192.168.1.121. but when I try to access my local host using local ip from other devices like pc or mobile, its unreachable.I also have the same problem with other webservers like nginx.

Comment: Do you have a firewall enabled on your system?

Comment: To check of the port is open: nmap 192.168.1.121

Comment: @ThomasWard I have only ufw and it's inactive

Comment: @WayneVosberg result of nmap:Host is up (0.00012s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http.  
                                                                                                                            so the port is opern

Comment: Can you ping and traceroute between the systems?

Comment: @WayneVosberg  no I can't ping to my system. but  nmap 192.168.1.121 -Pn -p 80   find the host. but says 80/tcp is filtered

Comment: and "ufs status" and "iptables -S" both show no firewall? Are the systems on the same network or is there a router between?

Comment: @WayneVosberg thanks for your help. I solved my problem by temporarily disable all firewalls in iptables. now i just have to add new rules.